# Pointwise convergence of a series $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(e^{-\frac{x^2}{n}}-1 \right)) $

Tags: pointwise-convergence

Consider the series for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(e^{-\frac{x^2}{n}}-1 \right)
$$
Then I have to prove that the series converges pointwise on $\mathbb{R}$. To prove this is all I need is to let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and prove that the limit
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(e^{-\frac{x^2}{n}}-1 \right)
$$
exists?
It is obvious that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow 0$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}} -1 \rightarrow 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and thus the product of the limits is also equal to $0$. Thus the series must converge pointwise. Is this ok? Or do I need anything else? Thanks for your help.

Comment: $a_n\to 0$ doesn't imply that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges. Can you compare the decay of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(e^{-\frac{x^2}{n}}-1 \right)$ and $\frac1{n^c}$ for say $c=4/3$ ?

Comment: Would I have to use asymptotic equivalents as Bernard did? I am not sure we have even heard that in our course. Thus I may not be able to use it.

Comment: Would I be able to use Weiterstrass M-test to prove this as uniform convergence also implies pointwise convergences?

Answer (score 1):

That is not enough. From $\frac1{\sqrt n}\to 0$, you cannot deduce that the series  $\sum\limits_{n\ge 1}\frac1{\sqrt n}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt n}=\sum\limits_{n\ge 1}\frac1n$ converges. You can obtain the convergence in the case of your series by considering *asymptotic equivalents*:

We have $e^{-\frac{x^2}{n}}-1\sim_\infty -\frac{x^2}n$, so
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Bigl(\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{x^2}{n}}-1 \Bigr)\sim_\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\biggl(-\frac{x^2}{n}\biggr)=-\frac{x^2}{n^{\tfrac 32}}, $$
which is the general term of a convergent $p$-series.